# Production server Error - All pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7, connection-string, connection-pooling, application-pool

In ASP.NET web applicaiton, it gives below excpetion some times when large number of users are accessing site.

`Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.`

Can you please guide me how i could trouble shoot and put resolution condition ?

In connection string adde d- "Max Pool" size as 500.

Hosted site on IIS 7 - server 2008

This issue come on productin server.

Thank You

Comment: Search for a static connection in the web-application then remove static. Always close the connection as soon as possible f.e. with `using`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705637/executereader-requires-an-open-and-available-connection-the-connections-curren/9707060#9707060

Comment: hmm... using sqlhelper so, it manages open close connction...

Comment: It's difficult to help without code. Maybe you have a loop which opens a connection or calls a method which opens it.

Comment: Even though, i receive this error, error was logged into database.. so, i have doubt - if connection pool is reached at max level though how it could log the exception into database.

Comment: How do you log at all?  However, these are  related questions, maybe they will help you to find the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848239/how-to-solve-max-connection-pool-error

Comment: I just log using - sql clien. No any logger mechanism used (log4net or any). hmm What are the settings to do on IIS or web.config about increase the Application pool size ?

Comment: I don't know what _"I just log using - sql clien"_ means. However, if it's not the application that logs but the sql-server than ... why should the database not log the error? Only your application's max-pool-size was exceeded. I would not increase it, instead search the reason. However, if you want to increase it anyway you do so in the connection-string.

Comment: Microsoft SQL HELPER contains static methods for executequery,dataset retrival and other accees methods.. but In code, it initialize new sql connection object and new sql command object.Though, i have doubt `static` method scope may impact in web application. do you think?