# SQL Server Error while pulling hundreds of records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting this error when I try to get all the username password from production copied local database, I guess it is because of not closing the connection properly, but I am not sure how . I am using the Microsoft Enterprise Library, ant thought or comment about it?

```
 Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to 
 obtaining a connection    from the pool.  This may have occurred
 because all pooled    connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

this is the mothod that is getting the username and password and producing the error.

```
private Model.UsernameandPass GetUsernamePass(string AccountNumber)
    {
        Model.UsernameandPass model = null;

        string myConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ToString();
        SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(myConnection);

        using (DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Get_TheUsernamePassWordFromProduction"))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(command, "AccountNumber", DbType.String, AccountNumber);
            var result = db.ExecuteReader(command);

            try
            {


                while (result.Read())
                {

                    model = new Model.UsernameandPass();

                    model.Username = result.GetString(1);
                    model.Password = result.GetString(2);
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }


        }
        db = null;
        return model;
    }
```

I am getting the error in this line after program runs for a while.

```
 var result = db.ExecuteReader(command);
```

Comment: Looks like you are spawning multiple connections and are not closing them and eventually exceeding your pool size. Put a Using statement around you connection code piece or have a finally to close the connections..try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717789/in-a-using-block-is-a-sqlconnection-closed-on-return-or-exception

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because a connection cannot be established, not **only** because they aren't being closed properly. Check permissions for the user you're trying to authenticate against the database with. Also be sure to call `.open()`/`.close()` when/if you are programatically opening/closing connections.

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848239/how-to-solve-max-connection-pool-error). You may want to increase your pool size, or check for long-running queries.