# connection timeout daily in the morning time in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, connection-timeout

I am facing the same problem every day in the morning time.

**1)Server time out 
2)System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.**

i am having this exception daily at 4-5am in the morning. i tried recycling pool one day at 2am. but still the same problem comes at 4-5 am. then it solves when i recycle the pool  after exception occured.
is it really due to non availability of connections or network related problem.

please help thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670774/how-can-i-solve-a-connection-pool-problem-between-asp-net-and-sql-server  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848239/how-to-solve-max-connection-pool-error ?

Comment: the problem here is it is occurring daily at certain time of the day.@Emanuele

Comment: MAybe at that time of the day you have an high number of connections and some of those are not closed..